# Plot indices of a 2-level Pandas Multiindex Series against each other

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, series, multi-index

I have a pandas series with a multiindex that contains two levels. I want to convert this data to a regular dataframe in which the first level of the multiindex specifies the index and the second level of the multiindex specifies the column names.

```
A     B
0     J0    value
      J1    value
      J2    value  
1     J0    value
      J1    value
      J2    value
```

I want to go from the above situation to the situation below and it concerns a relatively large dataset with thousands of entries on the A level and hundreds of entries on the B level.

```
    J0     J1     J2
0   value  value  value
1   value  value  value
```

I do see possibilities to do this with a loop, but that would mean a significant performance hit. I was wondering if there are some more performant ways.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your `dataframe` is stored in a variable named `'df'`

Now:-

```
df.index.names=[None,None]
df.columns=['']
```

Just use `unstack()` method:-

```
df=df.unstack()
```

You will get your desired output

Comment: I knew there had to be a trivial solution, thanks for helping me find it!